# JS-RegEx not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has one or more {numeric}_{numeric} combinations (separated with comma) and I'd like to remove one specific combo.

`('6_4,6_5,6_6').replace('\d+_5(,|$)','');`

but it's not working as expected and I just do not see why. (tested in Firefox JS-Console)

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys! Now, there's an added complication, because that '5' in the RegEx is contained in a var and needs to somehow get into the string. The obvious approach `var str = '\d+_' + 5 + '(,|$)'; var rx = new RegExp(str); '6_4,6_5,6_6'.replace(rx,'');`does not do it. Ideas?

Comment: Ok, got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `/.../` delimiters in stead of `'...'`, otherwise Javascript will try to match that String (not your expression).

```
'6_4,6_5,6_6'.replace(/\d+_5(,|$)/,'');
```

Also, the `()` around your initial String were unnecessary (although did not cause any problems).

Answer (score 2):

You are telling it to replace a string.

```
.replace(/\d+_5/,'');
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing the regexp as a string, not as a regexp.  Try:

```
('6_4,6_5,6_6').replace(/\d+_5(,|$)/,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regex syntax with / and not a string

```
('6_4,6_5,6_6').replace(/\d+_5(,|$)/,'');
```